# Manipulating a stream inside a using statement

Tags: c#, stream, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm handling uploads in .NET Core, which are passed in as [`IFormFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile). I need to manipulate the stream to remove Exif data before I ultimately pass the file to be saved. I don't know how to handle this, however. I'm trying the code below, but it doesn't work because `stream` is readonly inside a `using` statement.

What is the correct way to do something like this?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImage(IFormFile image)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // image is IFormFile
        await image.CopyToAsync(stream);

        // doesn't work, stream is readonly
        stream = StripExif(stream);

        // save stream
    }

    return Ok();
}

public static Stream StripExif(Stream stream)
{
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    // remove Exif data

    return stream;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the typo fix, Steve. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StripExif` is not actually creating a new `Stream`, rather, it's mutating the `Stream` passed to it, so *it shouldn't be returning a `Stream` at all*.  When the caller then modifies the call to reflect that it mutates the parameter, rather than creating a new stream, the problem goes away:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImage(IFormFile image)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // image is IFormFile
        await image.CopyToAsync(stream);

        StripExif(stream);

        // save stream
    }

    return Ok();
}

public static void StripExif(Stream stream)
{
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    // remove Exif data
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but the stream itself isn't being manipulated when I do this. Not sure if it's a problem with the Exif stripping itself or if the stream isn't being altered, I'll have to mess with it.

Comment: @vaindil In the code that you showed, the same stream is being returned, so there's no point in returning it.  If you're actually creating a new stream, rather than simply mutating the provided stream, then that's different than the example you provided.

Comment: I just verified, the stream passed in is not being altered with the code you provided. The image library is handling the code properly. I don't know if I'm handling the stream improperly back in the main function, but it's not touched.

Comment: @vaindil Then the code that you showed is not a representative example of what your actual problem is.  The code that you showed was the stream being passed in being the one returned.

Comment: It is correct, it's exactly copied from my code but with the extraneous stuff removed. I can't get it to work with either my method or the two answers currently on this question, so for the moment I've moved the StripExif code into the UploadImage code. It works correctly that way.

Comment: @vaindil The code that you've shown will only ever return the exact stream provided, so the stream returned will never be any different than the one provided; it's the same stream.  If you're observing it be a different stream, then the code that you showed is not in fact a representative example of what your real code is.  Either you are passing back the same stream, and have some problem with the caller, or the method is actually constructing a new stream, contrary to what your example shows.  One of the two is the case.

Comment: Okay, I was altering the exact same stream, but it looks like the image library needed me to seek back to the beginning of the stream before saving the image to it, so I corrected that and now your code works perfectly. Sorry for the confusion, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The using is only having a problem because you are trying to assign to the using variable. You could create a new `MemoryStream` in `StripExif`, and then assign the result of `StripExif` to a new stream variable.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImage(IFormFile image)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // image is IFormFile
        await image.CopyToAsync(stream);

        var strippedStream = StripExif(stream);

        // save strippedStream, not stream.
    }

    return Ok();
}

public static MemoryStream StripExif(MemoryStream stream)
{
    var result = new MemoryStream();

    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    // remove Exif data from result

    return result;
}
```

Updated :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImage(IFormFile image)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream())
    {
        // image is IFormFile
        await image.CopyToAsync(stream);

        var strippedStream = StripExif(stream, writer);

        // save strippedStream, not stream.
    }

    return Ok();
}

public static void StripExif(MemoryStream stream, StreamWriter writer)
{
    // lets assume for sake of example that removing ExIf just removes the
    // the first 10 characters of the stream
    stream.Seek(10, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    writer.Write(stream.ReadToEnd());        
}
```

Comment: Does that defeat the purpose of the using statement though? If I'm creating a new stream it still needs to be disposed, doesn't it?

Comment: It doesn't defeat the purpose, because stream needs to be retrieved from iFormFile before it can be worked with. And yes you are correct, the returned stream would still need to be disposed, but it would have to be disposed in UploadImage by manually closing the stream. Another option would be to create a StreamWriter that gets passed into StripExif (I'll add some code)

Comment: The updated `StripExif` returns void but a return value is referenced in `UploadImage`, not sure what it's supposed to be.